# How do I re-assign a function name in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a problem in C++ that is similar to this example problem.  In this case I have two member-functions that have an identical interface.  Based on the information in a string passed to the super function, I would like to assign one of the two member functions to the variable `class_func`.  Is there a way to do this?

```
// test.hpp
class TestClass
{
public:
    double master_function(double a, double b, std::string func_name);
private:
    double add(double a, double b);
    double subtract(double a, double b);
};

// test.cpp
double TestClass::master_function(double a, double b, std::string func_name)
{
    if (func_name == std::string("Add") const auto& class_func = add;
    else const auto& class_func = subtract;
    return class_func(a, b);
}
// =========================================================================

double TestClass::add(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
// =========================================================================

double TestClass::subtract(double a, double b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

In other words, I am trying to assign the member-function `add` or `subtract` to the name `class_func`, so the code underneath the `if` statement in `master_function` can be uniform regardless of which function the user wants to use.  In the form shown below I get the error `Reference to non-static member function must be called out`, but I am not totally sure what this means or how to fix it.  In addition, I am using a C++17 compiler, so if there is a modern approach that works best with C++17 I would be interested in learning it.

Comment: If `func_name` is a runtime string then there's no other choice then to use some hashmap, e.g. std::unordered_map.

Comment: Could you just use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)? Rather than passing a `std::string` your function would take a `std::function` and the user would dictate what to call? I think `add` and `subtract` wouldn't be able to be `private` which might defeat the purpose.

Comment: You should read a bit about how scope works, and probably always use braces. Both would show you that what you're hoping to do isn't possible the way you've written it. You could certainly have a function pointer that you assign or a map of name -> function but it isn't clear why you need that. Your example, as written, is simple to do without the unnecessary indirection.

Comment: Unrelated: Do you really need a variable in-between? `return func_name == std::string("Add") ? add(a, b) : subtract(a, b);`

Comment: @Retired Ninja: you are right this simple problem can be solved in a much simpler way; however, this is not the real problem I am working on, instead this is a much simpler example that highlights the same problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term you are looking for is *member function pointer*, but we can do without explicitly specifying that type. The problem with your code is not only in the way you try to refer to a member function (that would be `&TestClass::add`), but also that you create those aliases in a nested scope (under `if`/`else`), meaning they won't be visible in the `return` statement.

The simplest change is this:

```
auto class_func = &TestClass::add; // pick one default

if (func_name == "Subtract")
{
    class_func = &TestClass::subtract;
}
else
{
    assert(func_name == "Add"); // optional
}

return class_func(a, b);
```

This works because the `add` and `subtract` functions have the exact same type:

```
double (TestClass::*)(double a, double b)
```

But yeah, why are those functions not `static`? They do not work with a class' instance. Make them `static` and the above will still work, just note that the type of `class_fun` will be a simple function pointer:

```
double (*)(double a, double b)
```

---

Now that you know the types, you could change this in a way that does not privilege one function before the other in the code:

```
decltype(&TestClass::add) class_func = nullptr;

if (func_name == "Add")
{
    class_func = &TestClass::add;
}
else if (func_name == "Subtract")
{
    class_func = &TestClass::subtract;
}

assert(class_func != nullptr);
return class_func(a, b);
```

As mentioned in the comments, as that `if`-`else` chain starts to get longer, it makes more and more sense to use a (hash)map between strings and function pointers.

Comment: You could also make it a template `template <typename F> double master_function(double a, double b, F &&f) { return f(a, b); }` and then call it with `master_function(1.1, 2.2, std::plus<void>{})`.

Comment: Yes, that is how we do generic programming in C++, so I am hoping @Jon really wanted a run-time selection of behavior (based on run-time values, not compile-time types).

Comment: @LogicStuff you are correct, I am looking for run time behavior