# Assigning member functions to a property of an instance member

Tags: c++, function, c++11, callback, instance

I am still finding my way around C++ and have encountered a problem. I have a class containing an instance member of another class (can't inherit from), which includes a callback. I would like to register this callback to the parent class but am having difficulty.

After some digging around, I understand method != function, as an instance method implicitly expects an instance of itself (best way I can describe it!) and that `std::bind` was an option, but I can't get this to work when the signature is not `<void(void)>`.

I also read about implementing as an interface, similar to a delegate (I come from a Swift background), which was also appealing.

Here is a barebones version of what I am trying to achieve:

```cpp
class ChildClass
{
public:
    std::function<int(int)> callback;
};

class MainClass
{
public:
    ChildClass childClass;

    MainClass()
    {
        this->childClass.callback = this->square;
    }

private:
    int square(int i)
    {
        return i * i;
    }
};
```

I understand mismatching types are causing the error, but I have no idea how I can make them play together.

Comment: For a member function you need a member function pointer. Since that function doesn't need to be in the class you'd have an easier time if it was a free function.

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56212392/how-do-i-re-assign-a-function-name-in-c

Comment: You are right, in my original implementation it was a free function, but I had to move it into a member as I would be using the state within (squaring was just as a demo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (with capturing `this`).

```
MainClass()
{
    this->childClass.callback = [this](int i) { return this->square(i); };
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ep62Pm2iKr0jGrtA)

Or if you want to stick to [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
MainClass()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    this->childClass.callback = std::bind(&MainClass::square, this, _1);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kIKpkMKfNCSwV6Tq)

And see [Bind Vs Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1930903/3309790) and [When should I use std::bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15598607/3309790)

Comment: Worked perfectly! I was close, just never marked any placeholders. Thanks!